# how to stop Action Manager Trigger?

Tags: javascript, babylonjs, transactionmanager

Am using trigger code

```
    var rotate = function (mesh) {
                    mesh.actionManager = new BABYLON.ActionManager(scene);
                    scene.actionManager.registerAction(new BABYLON.IncrementValueAction(BABYLON.ActionManager.OnEveryFrameTrigger, mesh, "rotation.y", 0.03));
                    }
rotate(resultMesh);
```

how to stop the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Save your action to var a. Later in code use:

```
for(var i = actionManager.actions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   var action = actionManager.actions[i];
   if (action == a) {
     actionManager.actions.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

..and the trigger is removed :)

Comment: Removed trigger stops on removal.